# Xamarin android google maps missing SupportMapFragment

Tags: xamarin, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to use google maps API in my xamarin android project.  I followed the sample application and was able to get it to work.

https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/MapsAndLocationDemo_v2

However, in my app, it seems I am missing classes in the Android.Gms.Maps namespace, specifically SupportMapFragment.  I copied the google-play-services_lib folder from my SDK to the sample app, got it to work, then copied this folder to my App.  I don't understand what could be different.

Demo Project:

[image: sampleproject]

My Project:

[image: myproject]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to be clear, you copied the GooglePlayServices binding project along with the `google-play-services_lib` from your copy of `MapsAndLocationDemo_v2` over to your new solution?

If that is what you did, the the GooglePlayServices binding project should compile correctly, so here are a couple of things to check:

1. Update the `project.properties` linked file in your GooglePlayServices binding project - maybe it is an invalid reference
2. Is the Target Framework for your Xamarin.Android project is set to API level 8? You need to set this from the Project Options in Visual Studio.
3. Your Xamarin.Android project must reference `Mono.Android.Support.v4`.
4. Observe the log output when building the project. There should be a lot of warning, but are there any compile errors from the GooglePlayServices binding?

Comment: I was missing Mono.Android.Support.v4 in my android project, and then I was not inheriting from FragmentActivity (so missing it's members as well).

Answer (score 0):

`SupportMapFragment` comes from the Android support library, not the Google Play Services SDK:
http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html

To get the `SupportMapFragment` reference in your project, you'll need to copy the file from your Android SDK:

`<android-sdk>/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar`

into your Android project `libs` directory.

Clean and build, and this should do it.

Comment: This is for a Java based project, not for a Xamarin.Android project.